# What are these fixation claws called?

Tags: mounting

The balcony of our rented flat is based on metal pillars with indents. The balustrade is fixed to the pillars with kind of claws that stick into the indents. I'd like to use the same indents to fix a lamp, plants etc. without damaging the pillar. How could one name this claws, get them or construct a similar fixation?

[image: balcony balustrade]

Comment: They're probably specific to the manufacture of the balcony

Comment: What Steven said. This is likely a proprietary system. See if you can locate a product name/logo on any of the parts. (Looks like an interesting system, btw. Let us know if you figure out what it is!)

Comment: Ok, I've identified the company that installed the balcony. I will ask them and report later!